# How to show/hide shared catalog enabled categories in layered navigation in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, catalog, layered-navigation, category-listing, b2b

We have enabled the b2b extension.
When we select specific categories on shared catalogs, it hides only on the mega menu, but layered navigation still lists the categories.

> How can we hide it from layered navigations as well?